# Extract 3D coordinates from R PCA

Tags: html, r, canvas, pca

I am trying to find a way make 3D PCA visualization from R more portable;
I have run a PCA on 2D matrix using `prcomp()`.

1. How do I export the 3D coordinates of data points, along with labels and colors (RGB) associated with each?
2. Whats the practical difference with `princomp()` and `prcomp()`?
3. Any ideas on how to best view the 3D PCA plot using HTML5 and canvas?

Thanks!

Comment: You're better off asking these as separate questions (particularly question 3).

Comment: You have to provide more information. What is your data, is your 2d matrix a cov matrix, what is the meaning of RGB? In your field this kind of analysis might be obvious, but PCA is applied to a vast amount of subject areas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example to work from:

```
pc <- prcomp(~ . - Species, data = iris, scale = TRUE)
```

1. The axis scores are extracted from component `x`; as such you can just write out (you don't say how you want the exported) as CSV using:

   ```
   write.csv(pc$x[, 1:3], "my_pc_scores.csv")
   ```

   If you want to assign information to these scores (the colours and labels, which are not something associated with the PCA but something you assign yourself), then add them to the matrix of scores and then export. In the example above there are three species with 50 observations each. If we want that information exported alongside the scores then something like this will work

   ```
   scrs <- data.frame(pc$x[, 1:3], Species = iris$Species,
                      Colour = rep(c("red","green","black"), each = 50))
   write.csv(scrs, "my_pc_scores2.csv")
   ```

   `scrs` looks like this:

   ```
   > head(scrs)
           PC1        PC2         PC3 Species Colour
   1 -2.257141 -0.4784238  0.12727962  setosa    red
   2 -2.074013  0.6718827  0.23382552  setosa    red
   3 -2.356335  0.3407664 -0.04405390  setosa    red
   4 -2.291707  0.5953999 -0.09098530  setosa    red
   5 -2.381863 -0.6446757 -0.01568565  setosa    red
   6 -2.068701 -1.4842053 -0.02687825  setosa    red
   ```

   **Update** missed the point about RGB. See `?rgb` for ways of specifying this in R, but if all you want are the RGB strings then change the above to use something like

   ```
                      Colour = rep(c("#FF0000","#00FF00","#000000"), each = 50)
   ```

   instead, where you specify the RGB strings you want.
2. The essential difference between `princomp()` and `prcomp()` is the algorithm used to calculate the PCA. `princomp()` uses a Eigen decomposition of the covariance or correlation matrix whilst `prcomp()` uses the singular value decomposition (SVD) of the raw data matrix. `princomp()` only handles data sets where there are at least as many samples (rows) and variables (columns) in your data. `prcomp()` can handle that type of data *and* data sets where there are more columns than rows. In addition, and perhaps of greater importance depending on what uses you had in mind, the SVD is preferred over the eigen decomposition for it's better numerical accuracy.
3. I have tagged the Q with [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) and [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) in the hope specialists in those can help. If you don't get any responses, delete point 3 from your Q and start a new one specifically on the topic of displaying the PCs using canvas, referencing this one for detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out about any R object by doing `str(object_name)`.  In this case:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(50), nrow = 10)
res <- prcomp(m)
str(m)
```

If you look at the help page for `prcomp` by doing `?prcomp`, you can discover that the scores are in `res$x` and the loadings are in `res$rotation`.  These are labeled by PC already.  There are no colors, unless you decide to assign some colors in the course of a plot. See the respective help pages to compare `princomp` with `prcomp` for a comparison between the two functions. Basically, the difference between them has to do with the method used behind the scenes.  I can't help you with your last question.

Answer (score 0):

You state that your perform PCA on a 2D matrix. If this is your data matrix there is no way to get 3D PCA's. Ofcourse it might be that your 2D matrix is a covariance matrix of the data, in that case you need to use `princomp` (not `prcomp`!) and explictely pass the covariance matrix `m` like this:

```
princomp(covmat = m)
```

Passing the covariance matrix like:

```
princomp(m)
```

does not yield the correct result.

Comment: Are you taking a rather literal view of the description of the data? Consider `mat <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)`; this is a 2-d data set in the sense that `length(dim(mat))` is 2. The space represented by such data is 10-d, however.